# Update query with replaced values

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I want to update a table with replaced values of a specific field in MySQL. Below is my query.

```
Update tableA
set email=(SELECT replace(email,'www.','') FROM tableA WHERE email like "www%" and 
email like "%@%" and website="")
```

But it gives me an error that

> You can't specify target table for update in from clause

I've tried using inner join but getting the same error again and again. 
Please guide me where am I mistaking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a sub-query:

```
Update tableA
set email= replace(email,'www.','') 
WHERE email like "www%" and email like "%@%" and website=""
```

Comment: Got it.. Thanks a lot.